# Has there been a time the 2 NBA or NHL teams in the playoffs final series got there without losing any games?

Tags: trivia, nba, nhl, postseason

The Golden State Warriors and Cleveland Cavaliers started the [2016-2017 postseason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_NBA_Playoffs) by winning their first 10 playoff games.

Given their dominance, I'm wondering if there has ever been an NBA or NHL postseason where both teams advanced to the finals with perfect 12-0 record

Comment: So much for that :-p

Comment: And mind you, I'd think baseball is just as interesting a field as well for such a run.

Comment: I agree, but the playoff format in the MLB is different. Wild cards need to win more games to win the championship. Also not all series are best of 7. The question is as interesting for baseball, but doesn't match NHL and NBA format. So perhaps there can be a separate question for MLB.

Comment: Alas, suppose you're right.  Wasn't all that long ago that baseball mirrored basketball.  Things just keep on a changing.

Comment: I made a [separate question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/16180) for the MLB. The history of the MLB postseason format is interesting, compared to the NBA and NHL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*tl;dr: **NO***

**NBA**

There has not been a single team in the NBA going 12-0 into the finals. This is also due to the first round being a best of 5 game series until the 2003 playoffs. The 2000-2001 Los Angeles Lakers' actually went 11-0 into the finals before losing game 1 to the Philadelphia 76'ers. They won game 2,3,4 and 5 to win the NBA championship with a playoff record of 15-1. The best in history (so far).

***Edit***:

The 16-17 Golden State Warriors are the first team to ever reach the NBA Finals with a 12-0 record.

**NHL**

In the NHL the 1991–92 Chicago Blackhawks, 1991–92 Pittsburgh Penguins, and 1992–93 Montreal Canadiens had eleven game win streaks in the playoffs, but those streaks did not begin until later into the playoffs, such that each team lost opening round games.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the 11-0 was because first rounds of playoffs used to be first to 3 wins, not 4 as it is now. So essentially, both the 00'-01' Lakers essentially did the same sweeps as the 16'-17' Warriors.

Comment: @n_palum The quote "This is also due to the first round being a best of 5 game series until the 2003 playoffs" implicitly points that out, as well.

Comment: Oh yeah, not sure how I missed that.