# Has any two teams in the World Series ever get there without losing a game during the postseason?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb, postseason

Related: [Has there been a time the 2 NBA or NHL teams in the playoffs final series got there without losing any games?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16166/has-there-been-a-time-the-2-nba-or-nhl-teams-in-the-playoffs-final-series-got-th)

[MLB Postseason Format Timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_League_Baseball_postseason#Format_history):

- Before 1969, the team with the best record from the AL and the team with the best record from the NL during the regular season played in the World Series.
- Between 1969 and 1993, there was one playoff round before the World Series (AL/NLCS).
- Between 1995 and 2011, there were two playoff rounds before the World Series (AL/NLDS, AL/NLCS).
- Since 2012, there has been a play-in game for Wild Card teams, adding an additional game to the format for Wild Card teams.

**Has any two teams in the World Series ever get there without losing a game during the postseason?**

Answer (score 3):

> Has any two teams in the World Series ever get there without losing a game during the postseason?

**Yes.** However, all these instances took place during the "one playoff round before the World Series" format between 1969 and 1993. Each of these teams went 3-0 before reaching the World Series.

- [1969](http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/1969.shtml) - Mets vs. Orioles
- [1970](http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/1970.shtml) - Orioles vs. Reds
- [1975](http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/1975.shtml) - Reds vs. Red Sox

---

Between 1969 and 1993, 14 teams reached the World Series without losing a game. Since 1995, two teams have reached the World Series without losing a game:

- [2007 Rockies](http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2007.shtml) (3-0 NLDS, 4-0 NLCS)
- [2014 Royals](http://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2014.shtml) (1 Wild Card play-in win, 3-0 ALDS, 4-0 ALCS)

The Royals were the first team in history to win their first eight playoff games<sub>[(1)](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2233364-can-royals-become-1st-undefeated-champion-in-modern-mlb-postseason-history)</sub>. The Rockies, along with the Reds in 1976, won their first seven playoff games<sub>[(2)](http://m.mlb.com/news/article/98575182/royals-in-elite-company-with-seven-game-win-streak/)</sub>. Given the format at the time, seven consecutive playoff wins gave the Reds an undefeated postseason.